# what does the "shutil.rmtree" do?

Tags: python

I saw the following codes on website:

```
import tempfile
import shutil

dirpath = tempfile.mkdtemp()
# ... do stuff with dirpath
shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
```

I know that "shutil.rmtree" is delete an entire directory tree. But why delete the directory just after it was built?

I fond one answer said:"If you use this in a test be sure to remove (shutil.rmtree) the directory because it's not automatically deleted after use." But after I tried, even without "shutil.rmtree", the directory  I just built will be deleted after restart computer.

So what does the "shutil.rmtree" do?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is, as it seems you've already figured out "what... the `shutil.rmtree` [does]". Can you clarify?

Comment: What part of the fine documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) was unclear?

Answer (score 3):

The directory is created in a temporary location that your system may choose to delete at some point in the future.

If you know you're done with the temporary directory created, you can remove it yourself using shutil.rmtree immediately.

Comment: But the code on the website following "shutil.rmtree(dirpath)" uses the directory to store something. If I remove it using shutil.rmtree immediately how to finish the following work?   Will shutil.rmtree remove directory in the future?